# An efficient way of finding out the data merge ratios

Tags: python, dataframe, data-cleaning, data-processing

I have been looking and never found a solution for it online. Say I have two datasets that I am trying to merge on a primary key. Is there a way to find out the mapping ratio of the two datasets in Python?

I tried googling it but maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing. If someone could point me towards a resource, greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: What do you understand as "mapping ratio", how many times on average each primary key is met?

Comment: Yeah! And figuring out the one that did not match so I could investigate the reason within the 'unmatched' rows.

Comment: add an index column to your original dataframes, compare the index in your merged dataframe and before-merged to see what index appears multiple times in the merged, and see what index does not appear.